# R: Extract data based on date, "if date lesser than"

Tags: r, date, if-statement, as.date

I have a dataset with two values for each `date` like this:

```
    date        x   y
1   2013-05-01  1   2
2   2013-05-02  2   2
3   2013-05-03  3   2
```

`date` is in the format `as.Date`, using the package `lubridate`.

Now I want to have the `mean` of the two values, except for a certain time span, in which I want to use the values of `x`.

I tried the following:

```
mean=(x+y)/2

newdata=ifelse((data$date < 2013-10-01 | date$date > 2014-04-09), mean, x)
```

but if will just take the `mean` for all dates.

Is it possible to use greater/lesser than relationships for dates? 
Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use a reproducible dataset like those you see when you type `data()`? BTW, what do you mean by "format"... do you mean something about the class? `as.Date` is a base function if I understand correctly, but it's not a class and the format is given by an `origin` statement...

Comment: I produced the example data with:

`date=c("2013-05-01", "2013-05-02", "2013-05-03", "2013-05-04")
x=c(1,2,3,4)
y=c(2,2,2,2)
library(lubridate)
date=as.Date(as.character(date), format="%Y-%m-%d")

data=data.frame(date, x,y)`

for which the above would for example change to:

`mean=(x+y)/2


newdata=ifelse((date < 2013-05-02 | date > 2013-05-03), mean, x) `

Comment: and yes, I meant class. Still new to R, sorry :)
typing `class(date)` results in `Date`

Comment: OK cool, thanks. That always helps when we can quickly replicate your steps. It looks like you've got a couple of other people actively providing solutions tho, so I'm going to leave it to them. No worries about the class/format confusion. Welcome to R :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you are not casting the comparison values as dates. Also the dates you used for comparison don't exclude any of the dates in the dataframe you provided so I'd expect the mean to be selected every time.

```
date <- as.Date(c('2013-05-01', '2013-05-02', '2013-05-03'))
x    <- c(1, 2, 3)
y    <- c(2, 2, 2)
mean <- (x + y)/2
df   <- data.frame(date = date, x = x, y = y)
newdata <- ifelse((df$date < as.Date('2013-05-02') | df$date > as.Date('2014-04-09')), mean, x)

newdata
```

I changed the dates in the condition to be more selective and I got `1.5 2.0 3.0`. It selects the first value from `mean` and the others from `x` which agrees with the condition I used in the `ifelse()`.

Comment: you found the mistake in my code. Chose this as answer as it corrected what I already did and its nice and short. Thanks!

Comment: @HenrySteere where does `lubridate` kick in exactly?

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
##
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(
  date=as.Date(ymd(20130904))+0:364,
  x=as.numeric(sample(1:3,365,replace=TRUE)),
  y=as.numeric(sample(1:3,365,replace=TRUE)))
setDT(Data)
##
xSpan <- seq.Date(
  from=as.Date("2013-10-01"),
  to=as.Date("2014-04-09"),
  by="day")
##
```

**Edited** - forgot to group by `date`

```
Data[,z:=ifelse(
  date %in% xSpan,
  x,
  mean(c(x,y))),
  by=date]
##
> head(Data)
         date x y   z
1: 2013-09-04 1 3 2.0
2: 2013-09-05 3 1 2.0
3: 2013-09-06 2 1 1.5
4: 2013-09-07 3 2 2.5
5: 2013-09-08 3 2 2.5
6: 2013-09-09 1 2 1.5
> head(subset(Data, date %in% xSpan))
         date x y z
1: 2013-10-01 2 3 2
2: 2013-10-02 1 3 1
3: 2013-10-03 1 1 1
4: 2013-10-04 3 1 3
5: 2013-10-05 3 1 3
6: 2013-10-06 3 1 3
```

I just defined `xSpan` as a contiguous sequence of days for which one of the functions is used in (in your example, just the identity function of `x`). Dates not included in this time span will use `mean` to determine their value of `z`.

Comment: `lubridate` was not necessary but I included it for the `ymd` function and in case you are using it for other purposes.