# How to get x days after certain condition in R

Tags: r, date, extract

I have a dataset with multiple dates and conditions. I would like to extract all the rows which start with condition place == "A" and all rows with start date of place == "A" and up to 7 days later. For example:

```
Date        Place       Value1      Value2
2018-10-27  C           20          8 
2018-10-29  A           10          5
2018-10-31  B           15          6
2018-11-4   C           17          9 
2018-11-8   D           18          5
```

And I want:

```
Date        Place       Value1      Value2
2018-10-29  A           10          5
2018-10-31  B           15          6
2018-11-4   C           17          9
```

As you can see it must extract the first row with place == A and all rows within 7 days later. The places after the first day like "A" doesn't make sense, like "B" and "C". It must start with "A". It skips 2018-11-8 because that is more than 7 days from 2018-10-29.

I tried it like this question: [R: Extract data based on date, "if date lesser than"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689512/r-extract-data-based-on-date-if-date-lesser-than) , but I don't know how to extract the 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get corresponding `Date` value and select all the rows within 7 days from it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  filter({tmp <- Date[match('A', Place)] 
          between(Date, tmp, tmp + 7)})

#        Date Place Value Value.1
#1 2018-10-29     A    10       5
#2 2018-10-31     B    15       6
#3 2018-11-04     C    17       9
```

`dplyr` allows to perform operations without creating temporary variables in global environment,  the above solution can be written in base R as :

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
date_val <- df$Date[match('A', df$Place)]
subset(df, Date >= date_val & Date <= date_val + 7)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17831, 17833, 17835, 17839, 
17843), class = "Date"), Place = c("C", "A", "B", "C", "D"), 
    Value = c(20L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 18L), Value.1 = c(8L, 5L, 6L, 
    9L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

An option in `Base R` would be

```
# Find the difference in days 

tmp1 <- df$Date - df[df$Place == "A", "Date"]

# Time differences in days
# [1] -2  0  2  6 10

# And then just subset your df 

df[df$Place == "A" | (tmp1  <= 7 & tmp1 > 0), ]

#         Date Place Value Value.1
# 2 2018-10-29     A    10       5
# 3 2018-10-31     B    15       6
# 4 2018-11-04     C    17       9
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table( text = "Date        Place       Value       Value
2018-10-27  C           20          8 
2018-10-29  A           10          5
2018-10-31  B           15          6
2018-11-4   C           17          9 
2018-11-8   D           18          5 ", header = T)

df[, 1] <- as.Date(df[, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this can work though nearly similar to Ronak's answer, but without creating `tmp` variable.

```
#dput
dat <- structure(list(Date = c("2018-10-27", "2018-10-29", "2018-10-31", 
"2018-11-04", "2018-11-08"), Place = c("C", "A", "B", "C", "D"
), Value1 = c(20L, 10L, 15L, 17L, 18L), Value2 = c(8, 5, 6, 9, 
5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

#code
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  filter(between(Date, Date[Place == "A"], Date[Place == "A"] + 7))
        Date Place Value1 Value2
1 2018-10-29     A     10      5
2 2018-10-31     B     15      6
3 2018-11-04     C     17      9
```